# D3 ... Best (recommended) way to load array of dictionaries with multiple Y values

Tags: d3.js

I've data of the format (*simplified it to include only two values and 3 data points*);

```
data = [
{
    "date": "23-10-2018 13:16:55",
    "temperature": 30,
    "humidity": 46
},   {
    "date": "23-10-2018 13:15:25",
    "temperature": 29,
    "humidity": 45
},  {
    "date": "23-10-2018 13:14:55",
    "temperature": 28,
    "humidity": 44
}].
```

I would like to generate multiple line charts one for each parameter (temperature, humidity) vs date. The code below doesn't work for y generator since the value variable is not passed onto inside the generator function. What is the best/recommended way to solve this in D3v5 (latest version) Am not big expert on D3 though I love it a lot. Any help is appreciated.

---

```
        `enter code here`

        var values = [temperature,humidity];
        for (var p = 0; p < values.length; p++) {

            var value = values[p];

            var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

            var shiftX = p * 350 +  30;
            var shiftY = 0;

            //D3 generators

            var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                    .domain([0,d3.max(data,function(d){
                        **return d.value;**
                    })])
                    .range([height,0]);
            var x = d3.scaleTime()
                    .domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){
                        var date = parseDate(d.date);
                        //console.log(d.date);

                        return date;
                    }))
                    .range([0,width]);

            var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(6).tickPadding(10).tickSize(10);
            var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(6).tickPadding(3).tickSize(10);


            var line = d3.line()
                    .x(function(d){ return x(parseDate(d.date)); })
                    .y(function(d){ return **y(d.value)**; });

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually @rioV8 is right, you need to create each line by accessing the datapoint by key, and the keys need to be strings in this case.

Here is a running example with the following main changes:

1. Changed the datapoints for more effect
2. Renamed `values` to the more expressive name `topics`
3. Added a margin to the chart
4. Corrected date matching pattern
5. The axes need only be drawn once, the max y value is calculated by checking both topics. If you have more topics the logic needs little tweaking.
6. During the actual rendering of the lines per topic the data needs to be scaled to the coordinate system.

**File** index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>nested bars</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <style>
          svg.graphchart {
              border: 1px solid gray;
              background-color: lightyellow;
          }
          svg.graphchart text {
              font-style: normal;
              font-weight: normal;
              font-family: monospace;
              font-size: 10px;
              stroke: none;
          }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg class="graphchart" width="600" height="300"></svg>
    </body>
    <script src="node_modules/d3/dist/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="./graphchart.js"></script>
</html>
```

**File** graphchart.js

```
/** Variables **/

// changed data for more effect
var data = [
    {
       "date": "23-10-2018 13:14:55",
       "temperature": 8,
       "humidity": 14
   }, {
        "date": "23-10-2018 13:15:25",
        "temperature": 29,
        "humidity": 2
    }, {
        "date": "23-10-2018 13:16:55",
        "temperature": 10,
        "humidity": 20
    }
];

// which topics do we want to see
var topics = ['temperature', 'humidity'];

// svg specifics
var svg = d3.select('svg.graphchart');

// little margin
var margin = 40;
var width = svg.attr('width') - 2 * margin;
var height = svg.attr('height') - 2 * margin;

// the chart group
var chart = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);

// some colors for the lines
var colors = d3.schemeAccent;


/** Helpers **/

// needed to adjust date pattern
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S");


/** Axes: need only be drawn once **/

// x axis
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
        var date = parseDate(d.date);
        console.log(d.date);
        return date;
    }))
    .range([0, width]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .ticks(6)
    .tickPadding(3)
    .tickSize(10);
chart.append('g')
    .attr('stroke', 'gray')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

// y axis
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([ 0, d3.max(data, function(d){
        return Math.max(d.temperature, d.humidity);
    })])
    .range([height, 0]);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
    .ticks(6)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSize(10);
chart.append('g')
    .attr('stroke', 'gray')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .call(yAxis);


/** render lines **/

// render one line
function renderLine(topic, color) {
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return xScale(parseDate(d.date)); })
        .y(function(d) { return yScale(d[topic]); });
    chart.append('path')
        .datum(data)
        .attr('stroke', color)
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke-width', 2)
        .attr('d', line);
}
// render each line
topics.forEach(function(topic, i) {
    renderLine(topic, colors[i % colors.length]);
});
```

Anyway this is only one way to handle the task. The recommended way to getting acquainted with d3 is to check out the sound documentation and many examples at https://bl.ocks.org and play with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the trouble and the complete code. I'm trying to modify the code and will let you know how it goes ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the trouble and the complete code. I'm trying to modify the code and will let you know how it goes ...

Comment: No worries, my pleasure. Feel free to post a comment is anything is unclear.

Comment: Your code is working thank you in my test case. Will try in real case and let you know if i run into any issues... I have basically a time series data with multiple parameters like Temperature, Humidity etc ... for each date value. This data is then plotted in separate line charts (one chart each per parameter). Is there a preferred data format for D3? I mean i have the option from my uploader to store it in array of dicts OR dict of arrays. Is maybe JSON format the best (fastest) for rendering with D3? ... Thanks for the effort again

Comment: I would stay with the current JSON format, especially if the "dictionary of arrays" duplicates the date values. Think of it like this: the list of objects containing each measurement at a given point in time is your data. Each graph representing humidity, temperature and so on is a different view of that data. Each view gets the whole data set and just visualizes the topic it is responsible for. It might also be easier to implement an updating view of your data if each measurement is self-contained in one list entry. Check out `enter update exit d3` if you want to go that path.

Comment: Anyway, if the date values are not duplicated in the other format it really is a matter of taste, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use object indexing by string

```
var values = ["temperature","humidity"];

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0,d3.max(data, d => d[value] )])
          .range([height,0]);
var line = d3.line()
             .x(d => x(parseDate(d.date)) )
             .y(d => y(d[value]) );
```

Comment: Thanks @rioV8 ... I am trying to run this with the changes ... Will let you know how it goes